# Binding/passing data between viewmodels using Caliburn.Micro with Ninject and WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ninject, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I have an application which shows an options dialog.
Inside that options dialog I show a list of unicorns. 
When I select a unicorn, I can edit or delete it.
When I want to edit the unicorn it shows me another EditUnicorn dialog above the options dialog.
The EditUnicorn dialog contains tabpages, each to edit specific data of the unicorn.

```
Application 
--> Options window showing unicorns (OptionsView)
----> edit unicorn dialog  (EditUnicornView)
------> tabpages with usercontrols inside the edit unicorn dialog to fill in specific data about unicorn. (tabpages: EditUnicornSkillsView, EditUnicornFriendsView, EditUnicornGeneralView, ...)
```

A unicorn model in my GUI which is actually more a viewmodel...

```
public class Unicorn 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Strength { get; set; }
    public Health HealthStatus { get; set; }
    public List<Unicorn> Friends { get; set; }
}


public class OptionsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase 
{
        public ObservableCollection<Unicorn> Unicorns { get return MyData.Unicorns; }

        private Unicorn _SelectedUnicorn;
        public Unicorn SelectedUnicorn { 
            get { return _SelectedUnicorn; }
            set {
                _SelectedUnicorn = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanAddUnicorn);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanEditUnicorn);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanDeleteUnicorn);
            }
        }

        public void EditUnicorn() {
            // Is this correct?
            WindowManager.ShowDialog(IoC.Get<EditUnicornViewModel(), SelectedUnicorn, null);
        }
}

public class EditUnicornViewModel : Screen 
{
    // should it be like this? (or via the constructor or ...?)
    public Unicorn Unicorn { get; set; } 
}
```

The EditUnicornView.xaml contains:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="General">
        <ContentControl x:Name="EditUnicornGeneralViewModel" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Skills">
        <ContentControl x:Name="EditUnicornSkillsViewModel" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Friends">
        <ContentControl x:Name="EditUnicornFriendsViewModel" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The viewmodels for the usercontrols which are in the tabpages:

```
public class EditUnicornGeneralViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class EditUnicornSkillsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Strength { get; set; }
    public Health HealthStatus { get; set; }
}

public class EditUnicornFriendsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase 
{
    public List<Unicorn> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a Unicorn Model class in my GUI application, which is actually more a viewmodel,
I created this because each usercontrol in the tabpage has a specific viewmodels to only show the necessary data. I'm not sure if I did this actually correct.

Now the question is, as you can see the EditUnicornViewModel is (almost) empty.. How do I pass the selected Unicorn to the EditUnicornViewModel. 
**How can do add/inject/bind/set a property of one viewmodel to another property of another viewmodel? (ninject + caliburn.micro)**
And then the same problem occurs again: how do I set the specific Unicorn fields in each EditUnicorn(General/Skills/Friends)ViewModel from the EditUnicornViewModel?

**Edit:**

I don't think that this is a correct way of working (and then I would still not have a clue how to do it with the tabpages):

```
public class OptionsViewModel : PropertyChangedBase 
{
  // ...

  public void EditUnicorn() 
  {
     var vm = IoC.Get<EditUnicornViewModel>();
     vm.Unicorn = SelectedUnicorn;
     WindowManager.ShowDialog(vm, null, null);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro comes with a robust EventAggregator which offers a clean way to pass data round the system without supposing anyone is listening. This would be your best option as it means that N many tabs can listen and send messages. See http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator&referringTitle=Documentation

EDIT:

I just want to add, take a good read through the docs, Caliburn.Micro is based around the idea of composition, you should never have to call IOC.Get yourself. Basically your app should compose down the stack like so

```
 Shell > Conductor > Conducted ViewModels
```

Take a look at the samples in the repo as they show a lot of cool composition features.